# Injection from $\omega$ to set of finite tuples plus one element

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Let $U$ be an infinite set and write $\omega$ for $\mathbb{N}$:
$$ A=\bigcup_{n>0}\{f:n\to U \ f \text{ is injective}\}$$
That is, $f\in A$ is of the form $(i_0,...,i_n)$ for $i_j\in U,j\leq n$ and $n\in\omega$ with the extra condition that there are no repeated elements, i.e. if $j,k\leq n$ such that $j\neq k$, then $i_j\neq i_k$.

(a) Let $A\cup\{\perp\}$ be the set $A$ with an extra element. Assume there is a bijection $g:A\to A\cup\{\perp\}$. Construct an injection $k:\omega\to A\cup\{\perp\}$.

(b) Show that under the assumptions of part (a), there exists an injection from $\omega$ to $U$.

Now, what I've thought is: if $U$ is infinite, then $A$ must be infinite too, for it contains every singleton (this is an injection, so $|U|\leq|A|\implies|A|\geq \aleph_0\implies\exists h:\omega\to A$ injection). We also know that g:A→A∪{⊥}
bijection exists. Shouldn’t k:=g∘h:ω→A∪{⊥}
be enough, since it is obviously an injection?

Also, since $U$ is infinite by assumption, isn't it obvious that there exists an injection from $\omega$ to $U$?

Edit: It seems to me that the wrong assumption is that if a set $U$ is infinite, then there exists an injection $f:\omega\to U$. Could someone tell me why this is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

a) we can make injection in such way:

$h(0)=\perp$

$h(n+1)=f_n$ for $n\ge 0$

where $f_n$ is any injection from $n$ to $U$ (of course such always exist, the existance of bijection $g$ implies that $A$ is infinite, and it's easy to check that $A$ is infinite if and only $U$ is [if $A$ is infinite then $U$ too otherwise we can have finite amount of functions. If $U$ is infinite then there is always injection from $n$ to $U$ so $A$ is infinite too].

b) Yes it's obvious. $\omega$ is countable so always there is injection from this to other infinite set, you can just take any countably many distinct elements $u_0,u_1\ldots$  from $U$ and put $t(n)=u_n$, it is injection.

In general for every two sets $A$,$B$ these two are equivalent:

$\;\;i)$
$|A|\leq |B|$

$\;\;ii)$ There is injection from $A$ to $B$

Comment: OP didn’t say, but this exercise looks like it’s intended to be done in ZF, without using the axiom of choice.

Comment: Yes, it’s supposed to be done without AC, but where is it used in the solution given?

Comment: Yes we can prove that without AC. If we want to say about existance of injection $U\to \omega$  without AC we can do this this way.  We can say that there's a function $g_1:\omega\to U$ such that $g_1(0)\neq g_1(1)$. Then we can recursively make a function $g_{ n+1}$ to be a function s.t $g_{n+1}(x)=g_n (x)$ for $x<n+1$ and for every $x<n+1$, $g_{n+1}(x)\neq g_{n+1}(n+1)$. Now we can put $g(x)=g_x(x)$, and it will be injection as needed

Comment: @Antares: The problem can be solved without using AC, but your answer does use AC, in two places: (1) where you pick $f_n$ for each $n;$ and (2) where you say that any infinite set has a countably infinite subset (that is, an injection from $\omega$ into the set).

Comment: @Antares Your comment also uses AC in your recursive definition of the functions $g_n,$ when you define $g_{n+1}(n+1).$